# Creating DOMDocument in PHP

Tags: php, domdocument

```
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
  $dom = new DOMDocument;
  $element = $dom->createElement('div');
  $dom->appendChild($element);
  echo $dom->saveXML();
}
```

When I execute this code multiple times, something like this happens:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but I want the divs in a row like this:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

for some reasons it is working with `<button>`.

Comment: Use `saveHTML()`... unless this is XML? https://3v4l.org/hY4XB.. I can't get chained divs in either scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs some modification:

1. It's better to create `$dom` and `echo` results outside the while loop. Because in your example you need just one DOM object.
2. When trying to view the result using `saveHTML` instead of `saveXML`

There's lots of example here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();  
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
  $element = $dom->createElement('div');
  $dom->appendChild($element);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $element = $document->createElement('div');
    $document->appendChild($element);
}

echo $document->saveHTML();
```

Output (line formatted):

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```